# Disk Usage monitor for several machines

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have to write asp.net core service that will monitor disk space usage of several machines at particular time. This service will be called in my main service that is a separated project.
I've created a timer that will run this service every 5 hours, but I'm not able to figure out how to check disk space of every ip address. My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
            {
         "DuskUsageService": [
             {
           "RecurringMode": "1",
          "RecurringInterval": "1",
           "StartsOn": "00:00:00",
         "StartImmediately": true,
           "IPAddress": "1.1.1.1",
           "Username": "test",
            "Password": "test"
           },
          {
         "RecurringMode": "1",
           "RecurringInterval": "1",
             "StartsOn": "00:00:00",
            "StartImmediately": true,
             "IPAddress": "1.1.1.1",
            "Username": "test",
            "Password": "test"
            },
               ],
```

The idea is to create a service that will connect to the ip addresses and get disk space usage from there.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You didn't post any relevant code either. What you describe is already available in Windows since the 2000s - you can collect performance counters from multiple machines in a domain from a single machine, display them in Performance Monitory or collect them in logs automatically. There even was a web view for Perf Monitor at some point. The most scaleable solution would be to [configure a data collector set](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9185/create-windows-performance-monitor-data-collector-set/) to collect what you want from multiple machines

Comment: In fact, [reporting tools like Tableau do just that](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_perfmon.htm) to collect metrics. You can even [configure a data collector to write to a database](https://www.sqlshack.com/importing-performance-monitor-data-into-sql-databases/). Windows has a ton of features allowing to manage domains of thousands of computers without extra software or agents, through group policies, WMI, performance counters, Event log subscriptions

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that, but I have one main service that monitors several things on my application and I would like to add a service that will monitor disk usage and it needs to be in asp.net core. My question is what is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Use the operating system's features, not reinvent them. Whether on Windows or Linux, this is a solved problem with excellent solutions. On Windows, use data collectors. Even if you want to poll all machines yourself (why???) you'd still have to use WMI for this. On Linux you'd have to use the available services there

Comment: As for what's best - what are your requirements? Perhaps writing the data to a file is enough. Perhaps you need to write them to a database. Security is a requirement too, and storing cleartext passwords when you can work securely *without passwords* is a big problem